# Why is it suggested to power XOs with LDOs?

Tags: power-supply, oscillator, crystal, ldo, ripple

I've read in various places that crystal oscillator ICs require very clean power (as opposed e.g. to your usual 3.3V rail from some switching regulator) and one way to achieve that was via LDOs. ([Ref1](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slwa066))

However, the only thing that LDOs actually achieve is to stabilize the voltage against low frequency variations, perhaps out to several 10s or 100 of kHz. In contrast, XOs run at 10s of MHz typically, where most LDOs are completely inefficient at cleaning anything. Capacitors or LC filters are anyway used around XOs to provide sufficiently low supply impedance at the switching frequency. To be clear, yes LDO datasheet do claim high rejection at 10 MHz with suitable output caps, but this is not due to the active rejection, but because of the passive filter formed by the output cap. A passive LC filter likely achieves better rejection at 10 MHz than LDO + output cap.

The only reason in favor or powering XOs via LDOs would be, if their frequency depended appreciably on the supply voltage. However, this doesn't seem to be the case as shown e.g. in [this datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/3/ASEDV-1826261.pdf) from Abracon. Something like 100 mV low frequency ripple (which LDOs can clean well) would cause only something like 0.1 ppm frequency drift, if at all.

[image]

I am a bit puzzled by reference 1 above. It shows how low frequency variations of Vdd cause corresponding low frequency phase noise, but how? Wouldn't the oscillator frequency have to change to cause phase noise ? Or is that couple of ppb frequency drift enough to cause the excess phase noise ? 0.1 ppm of 10 MHz could only cause phase noise up to 1 Hz offset if I understand correctly (probably don't).

The application I have in mind is for a precision ADC (not RF). Therefore, close-in phase noise between 10 Hz and 100 kHz is especially relevant.

**So what is the benefit of powering an XO via an LDO (plus capacitors around the XO) instead of a basic LC filter that lets all the low frequency ripple through to the XO ?**

Comment: You might get -50dB at 10MHz with a light load and adequate output cap, do you consider that  "completely inefficient at cleaning anything"

Comment: *I've read in various places that crystal oscillator ICs require very clean power* Where did you read that? Show one or more examples. Xtal oscillators are used almost everywhere. In many devices like laptops and microwave overs, I would doubt that the clock needs to be that "clean" (jitter free). Only in certain applications, for example where a radio transceiver uses the Xtal osc. as a reference frequency, would I agree that a clean clock is needed.

Comment: The amplitude also matters, and by stabilising supply voltage, the LDO stabilises that. Any deviation from a perfect squarewave, and amplitude variation translates to phase variation (timing jitter).

Comment: That TI article relates to using Xtal oscillators in **synthesizers** which are used for generating LO signals in (radio) transceivers, just as I mentioned. No, that does not contradict the image, the image shows frequency variations over supply voltage and that is exactly the reason why the supply should be stable. I see no contradiction only confimation. Synthesizers multiply the XO's frequency by a certain factor. For example 2.5 GHz / 10 MHz = 250. If you have a 10 Hz variation on your 10 MHz that is then converted to 2.5 kHz which will harm a transceiver's perfomance.

Comment: ...at 10 Hz an LDO is very effective, capacitors that are very effective at filtering 10 Hz exist but are often **very large**.

Comment: This is as opposed to powering from a switching regulator where the regulator's own switching noise might get caught up by the RF parts. If you are just doing high precision ADC, then it's not as important to have a clean clock but rather a clean Vref. And the specialized voltage reference ICs you can use for such are often just a low noise LDO in disguise.

Comment: @Lundin yes I ended up deriving a voltage from the analog reference + opamp buffer as supply for the XO. Low phase noise is *definitely* of the essence for precision ADC if they are not only meant to detect DC but AC at >kHz frequencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your power supply only needs to be as clean as your application demands.

If your XO is driving an MCU, then you can get away with practically anything. If it's part of a low noise RF synthesiser, then you have to get your hands dirty.

All oscillators have a 'pushing' performance, which may or may not be specified. It's the delta(freq)/delta(Vcc). A good oscillator can tolerate a noisy power supply, and a poor oscillator may require a quiet one.

'LDO's are very different in their noise performance, and it's not always easy to interpret the data sheets to see what they are really specified for. Hint - if noise isn't specified, it's probably bad. Be prepared to trawl through a lot of data sheets to find a quiet one, there are some out there.

There is no LDO that beats a 'big C' final filter of the power supply before it gets to the oscillator, at least for offsets of 1 kHz +.

As a general rule, to avoid over-designing, build your prototype with bog-standard LDOs and minimal filters. Then test it. Then fix the problems that need fixing. If you start out with the lowest noise available LDO and big caps in your power supply line, then you may succeed, but you'll never know whether you could have gotten away with something cheaper. But it depends whether you're making one, or one million, whether that route is going to be cheaper overall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Neil, I have added two paragraphs below the image to explain a bit about the application.

Comment: @tobalt my answer is unchamnged, it depends critically on specifications. However, as your reasoning in those 3 final paragraphs is flawed, I'm not sure you would be able to apply them. So prototype it, test it, improve it.

Comment: So it is wrong that a 1 Hz frequency variation causes phase noise only offset by 1 Hz, if the frequency modulation itself happens faster than 1 Hz ? Looks like I have to do some simulations of phase noise itself to understand it better. :)2

Comment: @tobalt Yes, the 1 Hz variation is the depth of the modulation. If that 1 Hz mod happens at a rate of 1 kHz, then the phase noise offset is at 1 kHz. The depth of any phase noise on the XO will be reduced by the ratio of XO freq to signal freq, but still appear at the same offset. So if you have a 10 MHz XO clocking the ADC, and you're sampling a 10 kHz signal, the signal will have 60 dB less phase noise on it due to XO phase noise than the XO has. The phase noise will probably be dominated by other things. I've **always** been surprised by testing a prototype.

Comment: After seeing the effects of tiny frequency drifts well below 1 Hz on the phase noise spectrum with my own eyes in the simulation I have a strongly changed view on the necessity of low frequency supply stability. Thank you for poking me to it.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to your edit, as @user_1818839 pointed, unless you have a perfect (infinite bandwidth) square wave, changing the amplitude also changes phase even at constant frequency.  This is because the time when you cross the threshold voltage between 0 and 1 will change if the amplitude changes.  If you could have infinite bandwidth, than the edge of the square wave is vertical and this is not the case.  You always have some finite bandwidth though, so you need to keep your voltage as stable as possible.  Otherwise if your amplitude is jittering up and down, so is the phase you detect.

With respect to why you would use an LDO, their ability to reject low frequency noise can be very high, 50, 60, 70 dB is claimed in many datasheets.  Conversely, an RC filter with reasonable size will not be very good at this. Hence you really want both, at least in applications where a stable clock is important.

Comment: Thanks. I still have a little trouble to fully understand how the amplitude modulation would lead to noise in phase..I understand your reasoning but I will have to simulate it to see the quantitative outcome. I fully agree that a linear regulator is ideal to reject low frequency Vdd variation. I only have trouble seeing, *why* that would be so important for phase noise of an XO.

Comment: I was now able to reproduce the effect in simulation. A small supply voltage variation at \$f_{mod}\$ will lead to a sideband offset from the oscillator frequency by \$f_{mod}\$. However, the dominant effect indeed seems to be the tiny frequency variation caused by the supply variation, even if this frequency variation is << 1 Hz.